# How do i make a cell in excel stop calculating?

Tags: excel, timer, spreadsheet

I'm using wps spreadsheet which is similar to excel.

I'm trying to make a cell stop calculating at the end of the month, and keep the number of last day existing.

the existing code in k2 is:

=SUM(E2-I2)

For example: if on 01/31/2022 cell K2 says $2,000, then on 02/01/2022 it still says $2,000 but no longer grabs input from E2 and I2?

Thank you!

Comment: Copy paste special values.

Comment: Consider a `sumif()` formula. You are lacking information for a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that the date the CELL K2 is updated is in Cell "MyDate", use this formula in K2. When the month doesn't match it stop.

```
=IF(MONTH(MyDate)=MONTH(NOW()),SUM(E2-I2),K2)
```

If needed you can also add the YEAR.